# Does .NET's Mail.MailAddress comply with RFC 5322?

Tags: c#, .net

I've found that the following addresses don't trigger an exception when instantiating a `MailAddress` (`var address = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(<address string>)`):

- `a@!#`
- `a@___1`
- `a@<a repeated 64 times>`
- `a@......`

None of these should be [valid email addresses according to RFC 5322](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Domain).

Why are they accepted by this class? And should I use something else to validate email addresses?

Thank you

Comment: As the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress#remarks) make clear, this class isn't particularly concerned with adhering to a standard. It will accept some things it shouldn't accept and reject other things it should. Whether you *should* use it to validate email addresses depends on what you intend to do with them. The ultimate arbiter of address validity always remains the receiving mail host, and there are many ways of producing addresses that will cause trouble in other systems, standard or no.

Comment: @JeroenMostert My problem is that even if I use other `System.Net.Mail` classes with those email addresses validated by `MailAddress` it fails. For instance, if I use `SmtpClient` to send an email to `a@__1` it fails with error `System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException:Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: 5.1.2 The recipient address <a@__1> is not a valid RFC-5321 address`. So... what's the deal?

Comment: The deal is that the server rejects the address. `SmtpClient` doesn't care -- per the message, all it's doing is forwarding it. (Unless it's generating this internally with no server communication at all, but that would very much surprise me.) Note that a perfectly valid address could also be rejected, simply on the grounds of the recipient not existing at all. In that sense, it makes little difference if the up-front validation is perfect.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Here is another interpretation of a RFC.  The RFC does not say what the application should do when an invalid email address occurs.  So the c# libraries  (SMTP Client) for sending do meet the RFC.   One way of interpreting the RFC is to say the mail server (SMTP Server) should not send invalid emails.